# python subprocess.popen tshark works with some args, but not others

Tags: python, subprocess, tshark

When I execute a python script with this:

```
tsharkCall = ["tshark", "-a", "duration:6", "-i", "2", "-w", "thsark.pcap"]
tsharkProc = subprocess.Popen(tsharkCall, bufsize=0, executable="C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe")
```

A pcap file with the expected contents duly appears in the same folder as the script.

A second procedure to create a text file from the pcap does not work:

```
tsharkCall = ["tshark", "-i", "-", "<", "tshark.pcap", ">", "tshark.txt", "-V"]
tsharkProc = subprocess.Popen(tsharkCall, bufsize=0, executable="C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe")
```

I see "Capturing on Standard input" in the cmd window, but no "x packets captured", and no tshark.txt file appears in the folder.

From a command prompt in the same location, this does the job I am hoping for from the script:

```
>"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -i - < "tshark.pcap" > "tshark.txt" -V
```

It seems odd that one call works and the other doesn't.  Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess.Popen` by default bypasses `CMD.EXE` / `sh`, therefore command line I/O redirections (`<`, `>`) will not work.  You can get a similar effect like this:

```
tsharkCall = ["tshark", "-i", "-", "-V"]
tsharkIn   = open("tshark.pcap", "rb")
tsharkOut  = open("tshark.txt", "wb")

tsharkProc = subprocess.Popen(tsharkCall,
                              stdin=tsharkIn,
                              stdout=tsharkOut, 
                              executable="C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe")
```

Comment: Thank you!  I found that "-" needs to come right after "-i", but otherwise this is just what I needed to know.

Comment: @rlaing Hmph, tshark isn't obeying the proper conventions then.  I've adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This also works

```
tsharkCall = ["C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe", "-P", "-V", "-x", "-r", "C:\\Data\\PCAP_TEST_FILES\\test.pcap"]
tsharkOut  = open("tshark.txt", "wb")

tsharkProc = subprocess.call(tsharkCall, stdout=tsharkOut)
```